# Expanding image grid

Tags: html, css

Right now I have a grid full of images that are entirely different sizes. I want to have each of the images round up to a certain size, and so far all I have been able to do is use percentages for it to work.

Is there a way to make the images always stay a certain size?

```
<div class="grid-container">
         <div class="item">
        <a href="Games/exmpgame/index.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            <img src="Images/car_racing.jpg" alt="Failed to load" width="100%" height="70%" title="Game!">
        </a>
        <h3 class="caption">Example thingy</h3>
        <p>This is a cool bit <br>
        of text and stuff!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS for creating a grid:

```
  .column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block ;
    max-height: 200px;
  }
  
  .row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
  }


  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .column {
      width: 90%;
    }
  }

  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    column-gap: 50px;
    row-gap: 50px;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
    align-content: center;
    max-width: 66%;
    margin: auto auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**object-fit: cover;**

```css
html, body {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.image-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto 35px;
  max-width: 920px;
}

.svg-image-grid {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto 35px;
  max-width: 920px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

/** Screen readers only class from Bootstrap */
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);
          clip-path: inset(50%);
  border: 0;
}

/** Actual code examples */
/** Background */
.image-bg {
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 5px;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
}

.image-bg-placeholder {
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

/** Object-fit */
.image-fit {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
}

.image-fit-placeholder {
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-fit-img {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-position: center;
     object-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

/** Absolute positioning */
.image {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
}

.image-placeholder {
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-img {
  left: 50%;
  max-height: 150%;
  max-width: 177%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/** SVG */
.image-svg {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-bottom: calc(25% - 10px);
  position: relative;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
}
.image-svg svg {
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

/** Responsive grid */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .image,
.image-fit,
.image-bg,
.image-svg {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
  }

  .image-svg {
    padding-bottom: calc(50% - 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Techniques to crop and resize images with CSS</h1>

<h2>Image as a background</h2>

<div class="image-grid">

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/33704491300" class="image-bg" style="background-image:url(https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2809/33704491300_1df01dd919_z_d.jpg)" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-bg-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-bg-img sr-only" src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2809/33704491300_1df01dd919_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image as a background example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/33704488370" class="image-bg" style="background-image:url(https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2848/33704488370_9572b9d270_z_d.jpg)" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-bg-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-bg-img sr-only" src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2848/33704488370_9572b9d270_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image as a background example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/34088934825" class="image-bg" style="background-image:url(https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3947/34088934825_0acfe80a04_z_d.jpg)" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-bg-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-bg-img sr-only" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3947/34088934825_0acfe80a04_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image as a background example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/34088930595" class="image-bg" style="background-image:url(https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3956/34088930595_2b84cec168_z_d.jpg)" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-bg-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-bg-img sr-only" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3956/34088930595_2b84cec168_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image as a background example" />
  </a>

</div>

<h2>The object-fit property</h2>

<div class="image-grid">

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/33704491300" class="image-fit" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-fit-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-fit-img" src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2809/33704491300_1df01dd919_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image using object-fit example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/33704488370" class="image-fit" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-fit-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-fit-img" src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2848/33704488370_9572b9d270_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image using object-fit example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/34088934825" class="image-fit" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-fit-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-fit-img" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3947/34088934825_0acfe80a04_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image using object-fit example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/34088930595" class="image-fit" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-fit-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-fit-img" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3956/34088930595_2b84cec168_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image using object-fit example" />
  </a>

</div>

<h2>Absolute positioned image</h2>

<div class="image-grid">

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/33704491300" class="image" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-img" src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2809/33704491300_1df01dd919_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image using absolute positioning example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/33704488370" class="image" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-img" src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2848/33704488370_9572b9d270_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image using absolute positioning example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/34088934825" class="image" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-img" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3947/34088934825_0acfe80a04_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image using absolute positioning example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/34088930595" class="image" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-img" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3956/34088930595_2b84cec168_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image using absolute positioning example" />
  </a>

</div>

<h2>Image inside SVG</h2>

<div class="svg-image-grid">

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/33704491300" class="image-svg" target="_blank">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" role="img">
      <title>Cropped image using SVG example</title>
      <image xlink:href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2809/33704491300_1df01dd919_z_d.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" />
    </svg>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/33704488370" class="image-svg" target="_blank">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" role="img">
      <title>Cropped image using SVG example</title>
      <image xlink:href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2848/33704488370_9572b9d270_z_d.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" />
    </svg>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/34088934825" class="image-svg" target="_blank">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" role="img">
      <title>Cropped image using SVG example</title>
      <image xlink:href="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3947/34088934825_0acfe80a04_z_d.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" />
    </svg>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/34088930595" class="image-svg" target="_blank">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" role="img">
      <title>Cropped image using SVG example</title>
      <image xlink:href="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3956/34088930595_2b84cec168_z_d.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" />
    </svg>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).